# finding the values for $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ by restriction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Let $x_1+x_2+x_3=5$ and $1 \leq x_1 \leq 4$ , $0 \leq x_2 \leq 4$ , $0 \leq x_3 \leq 4$ .

How many $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are there?

Firstly i found the all cases such that $C (4+3-1,4)=15$ but i stuck in the rest.I could not make inclusion exclusion part. Can you help me? The correct answer is $14$.

Comment: Are the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$ restricted to the integers?

Comment: Non-negative integers.  Seems that $x_2$ and $x_3$ could be zero.

Comment: @mjw yes as you said

Comment: Judging from your calculation, you've already transformed the problem to something like "find the number of integer solutions to $x_1'+x_2+x_3=4$, where $0\le x'_1\le3$, $0\le x_2,x_3\le4$." The only bad case is when $x'_1=4$, which forces $x_2=x_3=0$. Hence one bad triple, $(4,0,0)$.

Comment: @WillOrrick it is different approach. i liked it. thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generating function. The answer is the coefficient of $x^5$ in $$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2,$$ which is the coefficient of $x^4$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2.$$ Expanding yields $$1+3x+6x^2+10x^3 + 14x^4 +\cdots,$$ so the answer is $14.$

Comment: thank you . i have not thought like that. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Generating functions are the easiest way, but I know absolutely nothing about them. So I'll illustrate how I might go about this problem. Assume $x_1, x_2,$ and $x_3$ are allowed to be in the range of integers $[0,5]$. Then the total number of cases can be found via a stars and bars calculation, and is $$\frac{(5+3-1)!}{5!(3-1)!}=21$$
Now we need to subtract for the cases where $x_1, x_2,$ or $x_3$ are $5$. There are exactly $3$ of these. Now we need to subtract the cases where $x_1=0$. This is another stars and bars calculation and the result is $$\frac{(5+2-1)!}{5!(2-1)!}=6$$
However since this includes the $x_2= 5$ and $x_3=5$ cases that we already subtracted, we need to add them back in. So our answer is $$21-3-6+2=14.$$